# Normality assumption in multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, error, assumptions, normality-assumption

It seems that this topic causes a lot of confusion from novices and even from some experienced professionals, so I wanted to clarify this for myself once and for all. I know there's several similar posts, but I haven't seen one that addresses exactly what my confusion is about.

In a couple of multiple regression tutorials and online resources I've seen it stated that there is an assumption of normality in dependent/independent variables for regression models. From [this article](http://Assumptions%20of%20Multiple%20Regression:%20Correcting%20Two%20Misconceptions) I learned that this is a misconception. Apparently it's the error that is assumed to be normally distributed, not the dependent/independent variables.

I've also seen people check a Q-Q plot of residuals after building an estimator, but from [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals) I found that error and residuals are not the same thing, and even if residuals are normally distributed, error may not be.

So then with this information, how do I actually check the assumption of normality of the error in the true model? Is this assumption even verifiable or is it really a true assumption in that sense?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's hard to think of *any* statistical assumption that is "verifiable" in the definite sense you seem to mean.  Assumptions can be *falsified.*  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability.

Comment: Is it the case that checking a Q-Q plot of the residuals happens to be some sort of proxy for checking the normality of error assumption? I just keep seeing people stating that error/residuals are not the same thing, then checking Q-Q plot of residuals anyway. I feel like I'm missing some important connection here, but can't figure out what.

Comment: If you only care about estimate and not inference, then you could drop the normality assumption. [Gauss-Markov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, because normality and regression assumptions are covered multiple times and extensively here and elsewhere. Can you explain what is your angle that is different from other discussions?

Comment: For one thing, I'm looking for specifically why people use Q-Q plots of the residuals to assess normal assumption of the error.

Comment: Good point. A reason should be given.